# multiple persistence unit on same transaction

Tags: persistence-unit

I'm trying to implement a transaction with 2 different database.
I currently have a persistence unit for each database, and wanted to write on a table A that exists on schema SA and write on a table B on schema SB, on the same transaction.

I'm using weblogic and eclipselink.

I've search a little, but found no example of using multiple persistence units on the same transaction.

Can someone tell me the correct way of doing this?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that, this should be implemented using XA datasources.
Each persistence unit should use a XA datasource, and then take part on a two-phase commit.

I now have:

- 2 datasources with driver: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
  and the credentials to login on both databases
- each persistence
  unit is called on a ejb facade, and those ejb facades are called on
  the global transaction.